# How to select non-consecutive elements from a Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have an array, what's a simple way of selecting non-consecutive elements? The second and fifth elements for example:

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
a.select_elements([1,4]) // should be ["b","e"]
```

EDIT

I just realized I can do `[1,4].map(function(i) {return a[i]})`. Is there a less verbose way?

Comment: If you wanted to store them to variables, then in the forthcoming ECMAScript 6 you'll be able to use destructuring assignment `var {1:x, 4:y} = a;`, which will set the `x` and `y` variables to the `1` and `4` members.

Comment: If you want something "built in", JavaScript lets you extend native data types using `.prototype` of the appropriate constructor, so you could write a simple method like: `a.grab(1,4)` that will return a new Array with those members.

Comment: I think the "verbose" way looks good. Hide it in a function if desired (I would avoid mutating the prototype of existing types as I prefer standalone helpers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safely (will not show up in for loops) add a function to all arrays:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'get', {
    __proto__: null, 
    value: function() {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).map(function(index){ return this[index] }.bind(this)); 
    }
})
```

Usage:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
a.get(1, 4);
```

---

Non-variadic version:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'get', {
    __proto__: null, 
    value: function(indices) {
        return indices.map(function(index){ return this[index] }.bind(this)); 
    }
})
```

Usage:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
a.get([1, 4]);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for something to make your code look shorter, you could extend Array to have this method:

```
Array.prototype.select_elements = function(indices) {
    var elements = [];
    for (var i=0; i != indices.length; ++i)
        elements.push(this[indices[i]]);
    return elements;
}
```

Now you can call the method you want:

```
a.select_elements([1,4])

["b", "e"]
```

Comment: Good solution, but I'd probably skip the array and just make it a variadic method by iterating over the `arguments` object. Though yours matches the code concept in the question.

Comment: You can do that, but just be aware the variadic method can cause a stack overflow if you want to select a lot of elements. A single Array argument will not overflow the stack.

Answer (score 3):

create a new array, with the elements manually:

```
var select_elements = [a[1], a[4]];
```

or create a function that constructs a new array from indices:

```
function selectElementsWithIndices(sourceArray, selectIndices)
{
    var result = new Array();

    for ( var i = 0; i < selectIndices; i++ ) {
        var index = selectIndices[i];
        result.push(sourceArray[index]);
    }

    return result;
}

var select_elements = selectElementsWithIndices(a, [1, 4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in. You can do this:

```
a.select_elements([a[1], a[4]]);
```

...which constructs a new array, uses the elements `a[1]` and `a[4]`, and then passes that to the `a.select_elements` function.